# Windows Phone 8 bind to string resource with format

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

My localized resource string, named `TextResource` has the value: `Text: {0}`. Where `{0}` is the placeholder for String.Format.

My user control has a DependecyProperty called `Count`.

I would like to bind `Count` to the text of a text box but also apply the localized string. So that the content of the text block is `Text: 5` (assuming the value of `Count` is 5)

I managed to figure out how to bind the localized string

```
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.TextResource, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" />
```

or the property value

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Count}" />
```

but not both simultaneous.

How can I do that in XAML?

PS: One option would be to add two text blocks instead of one but I am not sure if that is a good practice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have three options here.

**First option**: Modify your view model to expose your formatted string and bind to that.

```cs
public string CountFormatted {
  get {
     return String.Format(AppResources.TextResource, Count);
  }
}
```

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CountFormatted}" />
```

**Second option**: Make a converter `MyCountConverter`

```cs
public class MyCountConverter: IValueConverter {
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
    if (value == null)
      return value;

    return String.Format(culture, AppResources.TextResource, value);
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

```xml
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <local:MyCountConverter x:Key="MyCountConverter"/>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
...
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Count, Converter={StaticResource MyCountConverter}}"/>
```

**Third option**: Use bind-able converter parameter so that you can make a general StringFormat converter where you can actually bind the converter parameter. This is not supported out of the box in windows phone but is still doable. Check [this](http://www.shujaat.net/2011/02/wpf-binding-converter-parameter.html) link on how it can be done.

However, unless you are using resources to support multiple languages then it's much easier to just pass your format as a plain string to a converter.

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Count, 
                  Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter}, 
                  ConverterParameter='Text: {0}'}" />
```

You'll have to make a `StringFormatConverter` converter that uses the parameter in this case.

**Edit:**

Regarding third option, you can use the `IMultiValueConverter` in the link above to achieve what you want. You can add the following converter:

```cs
public class StringFormatConverter: IMultiValueConverter {
  public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
    var param = values[0].ToString();
    var format = values[1].ToString();

    return String.Format(culture, format, param);
  }

  public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

```xaml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=MultiBinder, Path=Output}" />

<binding:MultiBinding x:Name="MultiBinder" Converter="{StaticResource StringFormatConverter}"
    NumberOfInputs="2"
    Input1="{Binding Path=Count, Mode=TwoWay}"
    Input2="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.TextResource, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" />
```

I don't know if it's worth the effort though.

Comment: Thank you so much! Is it possible for option #3 to bind the ConverterParameter to the resource in the resource file? I tried that and it fails...