# Windows Phone two apps in one project

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to build two apps, the two apps are the same but one in English and the other in Arabic with different data items but the same design and code I want to build them in one project so I can modify both once,
Can any one help me how to do so ??

Answer (score 2):

I think you are talking about [Localization and Globalisation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff637522(v=vs.105).aspx)

Basically you need to add all your resource strings in your `AppResources.resx` and make use of it using the key. Here is a great [tutorial](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Preparing_windows_phone_8_apps_for_international_markets) about it .

A quick procedure is,

i) Store all your strings in the resource file along with a key
   ii) Refer the keys in your xaml (do not hardcode)
   iii) Translate manually or by using bing

Answer (score 1):

You need to localize your app in to different languages. Microsoft provides a `Multilingual App Toolkit` to make this process very easy.

Refer [this](http://wpdevkvk.wordpress.com/2014/02/18/localizing-your-windows-phone-app/) post to learn about how to achive this easily using `Multilingual App Toolkit`

Answer (score 0):

So you can do this within an app itself rather than going for two different ones. You can individually change the language of the string which you have to using the `Resources`.

These could some good references:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965329.aspx

[Windows Phone 8 bind to string resource with format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642830/)

Hope it helps!